# How to make a hybrid Debian 10 Installer 32 bit to 64 CPU?

Tags: boot, grub, debian-installer, bios

This is a problem with several solutions around the web, however, I didn't find any recent, not even for a Debian 8 or 9. In my Mac Mini 2007 without optical drive, the only systems I can boot are Mac OSX Lion, Windows 7 32 bits and Debian 10 32 bits. Ubuntu got a large documentation of how to install in old machines, but it won't boot at all any version or architecture, so I don't have a start point for Ubuntu.

I have rEFInd but Debian won't boot from USB trought EFI, only Windows or Mac OSX - no Linux will boot this way. The only way is to just restart with Debian 10.4.0 i386 ISO in a USB stick and it will boot directly. I think Debian is booting in legacy emulated mode. The booting structure of the ISO image is very different from a Ubuntu installer, maybe that's why it work. This is the ls...

```
autorun.inf  doc        install      pool                 README.txt
boot         EFI        install.386  README.html          setup.exe
css          firmware   isolinux     README.mirrors.html  tools
debian       g2ldr      md5sum.txt   README.mirrors.txt   win32-loader.ini
dists        g2ldr.mbr  pics         README.source
```

If it is booting by BIOS, it will execute the code in sector 0, right? Than what? I am thinking about to overwrite all files but boot directory with the amd64 distro, than edit the grub.cfg to call the 64 bit installer, mught work?

Any ideas?